Hebrew text in Thymeleaf is not displayed correctly
I have a Spring MVC application with Thymeleaf as the view technology. I have difficulty displaying hebrew text in my HTML. I have a simple HTML file with some hebrew text in it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>שלום</h1>
    
</body>
</html>

When serving this page using JSP (with Spring MVC), it appears fine. When switching to Thymeleaf, something goes wrong. I tried setting the character encoding on the Thymeleaf view resolver:

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

But it doesn't help.

Ok, apparently I needed to set setCharacterEncoding on the template resolver rather than the view resolver:

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
  SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }


